# How to stop/pause a prediction node from Google AI Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have deployed a model in Google AI-Platform and its running fine.  However, I rarely use the model and the billing us running 24/7.

Can someone tell me how to pause/stop the prediction node without deleting the model? So I can turn on and off the VM when I really need it.

I could not find any documentation or section in the console to do it.

Comment: You can check out this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/set-scheduling
This is to set a schedule when you want your VM to turn on and off when you need to.
However, I'm not sure it applies to the prediction node itself.

Comment: What the requirement of your model? Do you need lot of memory, cpus or gpus?

Comment: The requirement is low, I'm using the default setting of VM which is I think, the lowest one.

Comment: @LukeTerro The problem is that I don't see any instance related to prediction in my console.

Comment: @Ricardo Chen He You can store your model in Cloud Storage and use it whenever you want after running a GCE node but first youneed to undeploy the model.

Here's documentation for reference:
https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/deploying-models